# Print out widget tree in Flutter test

Tags: debugging, flutter, flutter-test

In Flutter, how can I print out the current widget tree in a widget unit test, in order to understand the current state of the UI for debugging?

(For example, in React/Ensyme, I could use [debug()](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/debug.html). Is there something comparable in Flutter?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [debugDumpApp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/debugDumpApp.html)

This will print the widget tree based on the [Diagnosticable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Diagnosticable-class.html) interface, which both Widget, RenderObject and Element implements.

Note that for custom made widgets, you'll have to implement a method for their content to display in that tree:
 [debugFillProperties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DiagnosticableMixin/debugFillProperties.html)

Comment: Looks promising, unfortunately it just throws an exception when I call it: https://gist.github.com/mdr/915a269a6a314d49f90041736480c5a4

Comment: Consider making an issue. That assert is very unclear.

Comment: By elimination, looks to be a problem in some of the theme customisation I was using. I will try and make a minimum reproducible test case and submit it as a bug. But otherwise, that works a treat, thanks!